Is there a way to adjust the file maxSize for the intelephense lspconfig
at my job we have a php file that is over 1mb in size. Intelephense won't run on it. Is there a way for me adjust the settings to increase the maxSize that it takes? I'm currently trying the following.
lspconfig.intelephense.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
                settings = {
                    files = {
                        maxSize = 4000000,
                    },
                },
            })

Thanks for your help!

See example at indelephense.lua in the nvim-lspconfig sources.
The settings table needs to have another intelephense key at the root level that you're missing.
In your specific situation:
lspconfig.intelephense.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
                settings = {
                    intelephense = {
                        files = {
                            maxSize = 4000000,
                        },
                    },
                },
            })


Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried this and it didn't work, do you know if there's a way to verify if this is exposed for neovim?

Sorry I don't use these plug-ins myself, so not sure what might have gone wrong, I'll go ahead and delete my answer, in hopes someone will know better and have a better answer for you
